# Why do these histogram functions differ, and why is one nondeterministic?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, histogram, non-deterministic

NOTE: This is a homework problem and the professor explicitly forbids soliciting answers from StackOverflow, so please limit your response to the specific question I have asked and do not attempt to provide a working solution.

I am asked to implement a function that computes the histogram of a single-channel 8-bit image represented as an OpenCV `Mat` with type `CV_U8`.

In this case, the histogram uses 256 uniformly-distributed buckets. This is the reference we are intended to replicate (using OpenCV 3.4):

```
Mat reference;

/// Establish the number of bins
int histSize = 256;

/// Set the ranges ( for B,G,R) )
float range[] = { 0, 256 } ;
const float* histRange = { range };

bool uniform = true;
bool accumulate = false;

cv::calcHist(&bgr_planes[0], 1, 0, Mat(), reference, 1, &histSize, &histRange,
             uniform, accumulate);

// reference now contains the canonical histogram of the input image's
// blue channel
```

I wrote the following function to calculate the histogram, which produces the correct results 45-69% of the time (p<0.05, n=66). Once when it failed, I examined the results and found no discernable pattern. All trials were conducted on the same test image.

```
Mat myCalcHist(const Mat& input) {
  assert(input.isContinuous());

  Mat res(256, 1, CV_32F);
  for (const uint8_t* it = input.datastart; it != input.dataend; ++it) {
    ++res.at<float>(*it);
  }

  return res;
}
```

The following function, on the other hand, more closely matches OpenCV's internal implementation in that it uses the idiomatic accessors and converts the `float` result from an `int` work matrix, but in n=66 trials it did not produce the correct result a single time. Again, I found no discernable pattern in the data.

```
Mat myCalcHist(const Mat& input) {

  Mat ires(256, 1, CV_32S);
  for (int i = 0; i < input.total(); ++i) {
    ++ires.at<int>(input.at<uint8_t>(i));
  }

  Mat res(256, 1, CV_32F);
  ires.convertTo(res, CV_32F);
  return res;
}
```

Why are the results for my first implementation different than those from my second implementation, and where is nondeterminism introduced to the first implementation?

Comment: Is `res` initialized?

Comment: @Chris I didn't think I needed to initialize it explicitly because (a) `reference` is not initialized explicitly in the reference implementation and (b) `Mat.convertTo` reallocates the result matrix as needed.

However, I have since added code to explicitly initialize `res` (see incoming edit) and it had no effect: the second implementation still fails 100% of the time.

Comment: you should initialize your matrix data with either (constructor) cv::Mat::zeros(size, type) or cv::Mat(size,type,cv::Scalar::all(0))

Comment: Use cv::Mat::zeros() or cv::Mat::setTo() to initialize res. If you only call the constructor of the mat, the memory is only allocated and not initialized with zeros.

Comment: how did you create Mat input?

Comment: in the 2nd code, ires has to be initialized, not res

Comment: @Micka this is the information I was missing; I had assumed that Mat would initialize its own buffer by default. I will accept this if you repost it as an answer.

Comment: The input in all cases is derived from a sample image that was read using `cv::imread` and split into channels using `cv::split`

Comment: @hxtk: There's a good lesson here: if your code is unintentionally "stochastic", you are likely reading uninitiated memory!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initializing the histogram matrix should work:

```
Mat myCalcHist(const Mat& input) 
{
    Mat ires = cv::Mat::zeros(256, 1, CV_32S);
    for (int i = 0; i < input.total(); ++i) 
    {
         ++ires.at<int>(input.at<uint8_t>(i));
    }

   Mat res(256, 1, CV_32F);
   ires.convertTo(res, CV_32F);
   return res;
}
```